# passing in a function as props

Tags: html, reactjs, react-props

I have imported a function from another file using import.  I want to be able to run it inside of a component, but I am not sure how to do this.  The imported function is a login method for firebase and I am not getting it to work. The function I want to run is loginuser.  I have commented where I call it in the component, but i can't get it to pass into the component properly.  Can someone please help.  Thanks!!

```
import { loginuser } from './redux/userfunctions'


class Login extends Component {



  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }


handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log("submit selected");
  const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData, this.props.history);  // this is where i call it and it is failing.
  };



  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

render() {
 return (
    <div className = "sign-in">
      <Topbar />
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
        type = "text"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        value={this.state.email}
        onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />

        <input
        type = "password"
        placeholder= "Password"
        name="password"
        value={this.state.password}
        onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />

        <button type = "submit"> Sign In </button>
      </form>

    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: I think a solution to this is using 'redux' & 'react-redux' packages & using the method `mapDispatchToProps()` which simply maps a function as a property.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed.  I'm only trying to pass it in one level though, so is redux really necessary for this case?

Comment: That's exactly why I commented this instead of making it an answer, but anyway that's what I had in mind

Comment: I might . wind up doing that.  Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: why are you calling it as if it was a prop? why not just `loginUser(userData, this.props.history);`?

Comment: that appears to solve my problem.  I'm not sure though because nothing is happening when I click the submit button so I will have to do some more debugging.  Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import a function you can just call it like it is. You only have to use the props if it's an actual `prop`.

So just call

```
loginUser(userData, this.props.history);
```

`Props` are a react construct. For further reading about how they work I'd recommend reading the [components & props section](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) in the react.js docs.